# Needing a example of how to style an EditText control in the Holo theme to be more like pre Holo

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to more or less copy a PSD that has older controls in it with also using the ActionBar in ICS they like the old style that has the actual box instead of the underline. how would i be able  to keep the holo theme and revert a control to the old styles?

Comment: I LOL when people use lots of TLAs like PSD and ICS :)  Q: What exactly is your question?  Do you want to code your app so that it uses "Holo themes" for Android 3.0 or higher, but reverts to reasonable defaults for 2.x or lower?  Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094478/how-to-maintain-backwards-compatibility-while-utilising-android-api-level-15

Comment: This post is enabling styles based on device version for the different styles from what I can tell. What I am asking is how can I make an EditText control not look like Holo EditText but for the EditText to be forced to the 2.0 style within a Holo style. Am I making sense??

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to show you how i made this happen as quick fix..

http://www.androidworks.com/changing-the-android-edittext-ui-widget

This covers the bases on how to style in depth .. and basically i built my own 9.png files..