# android intellij switch nullpointerexception

Tags: android, intellij-idea, nullpointerexception, switch-statement

I am trying to put a switch widget into my activity in IntelliJ.
When I do this the designer crashes with a NullPointException inside of android.widget.Switch.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState and a long stack trace.

The element is added with android:id="@+id/switch" which produces a compiler error: invalid symbol: 'switch'

I have to change the name to something else but "switch". Strange to see the system adding an invalid name but ok I could live with that.

But the visual designer still is useless when the switch is in the layout.
The only thing I can find in Google is a bug tracker entry describing this. But no solution.
What is going on there? Does someone know a solution?

Edit
I add the stack trace:

`java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.widget.Switch.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(Switch.java:825)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5158)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5158)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(FrameLayout.java:189)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5158)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5158)
    at android.view.View.onAttachedToWindow(View.java:11560)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:11937)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2415)
    at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:42)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:393)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:332)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:333)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:127)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.RenderUtil.renderLayout(RenderUtil.java:154)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$8.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:346)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)`

This appears in the designer view instead of the activity once a switch is added.

Comment: Show the stack trace please. Maybe the API Level?

Comment: stack trace added. Yes it is at API level. The whole thing happens in the designer only. I can run the app. Just the designer stops working if the switch is present.

Comment: take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757478/android-compoundbutton-switch-jumpdrawablestocurrentstate-null-crash

Comment: ok I did but I am not using a selfmade element, this switch is from the basically installed tools. My API level is 17 so far above the suggested 14. I tried something below 14 but also no success.In contrast to the user in your link I can execute the app but I can't see my view in the designer. Any other ideas?